# Flutter Custom clip paint like given below image with gradient and rouded cornor

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Round the corner with custom shape in flutter
Example would like shared image below

[image: round the corner with custom shape in flutter Example would like shared image below]

Comment: You can use direct image also and if u want to design it you can also use custom clipper

Answer (score 0):

You can just simply use `Container` decoration and corner to handle the view

[image]

```dart
  final double width = 400;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          width: width,
          height: width,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.deepPurple,
                spreadRadius: 14,
                blurRadius: 11,
              )
            ],
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topRight: Radius.circular(width * .05),
              bottomLeft: Radius.circular(width * .05),
              bottomRight: Radius.circular(width * .3),
              topLeft: Radius.circular(width * .3),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```